# how to convert Json Data to variable in EXTJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, extjs

i have data json which get from MYSQL. but i want convert from json to array data.

```
Ext.define('DWP3.store.konten.Coba', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.coba',
 storeId: 'coba',
uses: [
    'Ext.data.Store'
],


        fields: [
           {name: 'periode'},
           {name: 'Teknik Informatika S1'},
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'resources/data/load2.php',
            reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'view_aktif'
            }
        },
         autoLoad: true,

  });
```

i want convert data from json like this:

```
       var data= [
            ['2009', 94.7 ],
            [ '2010', 96.5 ],
            [ '2011', 98.6 ],
            [ '2012',  70.8 ],
            [ '2013', 83.3]
        ]
```

how can i do that?

Comment: Show us what you've already tried.

Comment: i want load new data to Json which get from Mysql..can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS stores take records as objects, not as arrays.

Lucky you: JavaScript arrays are similar enough to objects to process them with ExtJS stores. The array `['2009', 94.7 ]` is not handled any different than the object `{0:'2009', 1:94.7 }`, so you would have to do the following:

```
fields: [
   {name: 'periode',mapping:0},
   {name: 'Teknik Informatika S1',mapping:1},
],
```

(Note: I am not sure whether names with spaces are allowed. My tests did not use this name)

For further reading, please compare the documentation of ExtJS [`mapping`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-mapping) property.

I would also recommend that you take a look at the [`type`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-type) property as well, since I guess that you want to work with ints/floats.

Comment: my problem is i want load new data to Json which get from mysql. it is possible to do that?